# How to add headers to a csv using apache nifi

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I want to add headers to a csv file, to it I have used given instrcutions here. [Nifi: how to add custom header to CSV file](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-how-to-add-custom-header-to-CSV-file/td-p/190074), I have used `Replace text` processor and changed parameters as given here.

But final output just append headers to the first line.

Sample :

```
1,sachith,SO,1587
```

Expected output :

```
id,name,site,score
1,sachith,SO,1587
```

Output :

```
id,name,site,score,1,sachith,SO,1587
```

Should I use another processor or is there a missing conf?

Comment: just add a new line at the end of the replacement value

Comment: I have used `id,name,site,score\n` as the replacement value, but still same. `\n` was taken as a value.

Comment: Instead of \n, type shift+enter after your header line.

Comment: That worked. Can you please post this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using  `\n`, use `shift+enter` after header line

Comment: thanks a lot, i searched thru the entire internet and only this answer is valid!